# How to run function after 10 seconds not using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little script that have to show next images, so I wrote something like that

```
$(".img1").delay(2500).fadeIn(600);
$(".img2").delay(6200).fadeIn(600);
$(".img3").delay(8700).fadeIn(600);
$(".img4").delay(11200).fadeIn(600);
$(".img5").delay(13700).fadeIn(600);
$(".img6").delay(16200).fadeIn(600);
```

and now I wonder, how can I run function after last image? I don't want to use setTimeout.

Comment: @Phil maybe he could use `setInterval` instead :D

Comment: @TilwinJoy genial suggestions, keep it up!

Answer (score 1):

fadeIn takes second argument "callback" - see the docs: http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

It can be any function, and it's called when the animation is done.

Just pass an anonymous function there.

```
$(".img6").delay(16200).fadeIn(600, function(){
    alert("It's over, it's done!");
});
```

Comment: I tried that way, but when img6 fadesIn, then function starts (doesn't wait 2500ms)... :/

Comment: @Bob If you really dont want timeout, try a fadeIn with zero duration: http://jsfiddle.net/9vYXp/ or perhaps jquery queue()

Answer (score 0):

fadeIn has a 'complete' callback as the second paramter. http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

```
$(".img1").delay(2500).fadeIn(600);
$(".img2").delay(6200).fadeIn(600);
$(".img3").delay(8700).fadeIn(600);
$(".img4").delay(11200).fadeIn(600);
$(".img5").delay(13700).fadeIn(600);
$(".img6").delay(16200).fadeIn(600, function(){
    alert('Hello world!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`fadeIn()` lets you run a callback function once the function itself has completed its job, see documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

**JS**

```
$("#test").fadeIn(1000, function(){
    //--- do whatever you need once the fade in is completed
})
```

**FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/TFtt3/

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at this jQuery plugin:

http://jquery.offput.ca/timers/

The `oneTime()` method allows you to run code ONCE after certain seconds.

```
$('#myelement').oneTime('10s', function() {
    // do something after 10s
});
```

but in fact the underlying code of the plugin uses `setTimeout`/`setInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

Use another delay after fadeIn followed queue passing your function

```
$(".img6").delay(16200).fadeIn(600).delay(100).queue(function(){ alert("");});
```